Use old-style figures in textstyle and displaystyle math, but lining figures in scriptstyle? (libertine, newtxmath)
I’m trying to roughly recreate some historical typography.  Following the source material, I’d like my document to use old-style figures in text mode and in non-subscript math (i.e. under \textstyle/\displaystyle), but lining figures in math subscripts (\scriptstyle).  Overall I have Libertine as the main document font, using the packages libertine and newtxmath.
Switching figure-styles between text and math modes under libertine/newtxmath is adequately handled by the answers of this old question, but I can’t figure out how to configure them separately for the different math mode styles.
MWE for testing:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[oldstyle]{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

Consider 1987, when $\alpha_{1987} = 1987$.

\end{document}


Are you willing and able to use the unicode-math package (requires compilation under LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX)? Please advise.

@Mico: I’d prefer something compatible with pdflatex if possible, but a unicode-math-based answer would be welcome too (especially in case nobody can find a good solution without it)

One more thing: Should the widths of the Oldstyle numerals be fixed or proportional? (This afffects mainly the numerals 0 and 1.)

Updated Answer using fd file
You can modify the fd file used by the oldstyle font family so that it uses the lining font just at the sizes uses  by script and scriptstyle.
Normally you would be able to easily over-ride the definitions but teh package uses a lot of local conditional code and that seems a bit tricky but you can copy OT1LinuxLibertineT-TOsF.fd from its default place, which is probably /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/OT1LinuxLibertineT-TOsF.fd  and save it in the directory with your document and modify the entry for {m}{n} so that it looks like
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{LinuxLibertineT-TOsF}{m}{n}{
       <5.5><7.3> \LinuxLibertineT@@scale LinLibertineT-tlf-ot1
       <-> \LinuxLibertineT@@scale LinLibertineT-tosf-ot1
}{}

ie add the line for <5.5><7.3> to use the font with lining figures (-tlf instead if -tosf


Original answer
There isn't a high level interface but you can specify scriptfont0 without changing textfont0. This works with pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[oldstyle]{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  % force the non-oldstyle versions
  \sbox0{$ $}% force math setup
  \font\sfnt=LinLibertineT-tlf-ot1 at 7.3pt
  \font\ssfnt=LinLibertineT-tlf-ot1 at 5.5pt
  \scriptfont0=\sfnt
  \scriptscriptfont0=\ssfnt
}
\begin{document}

% save the values shown when [oldstyle] is not used
%\expandafter\show\the\scriptfont0
%\expandafter\show\the\scriptscriptfont0


Consider 1987, when $\alpha_{1987} = 1987$.

\end{document}


unfortunately after any size change LaTeX will reset the math fonts to what (it thinks are) the correct settings for each font so you would need to re-do the scriptfont0 and scriptscriptfont0 setting, either explicitly or perhaps patching that on to \glb@settings

Thankyou; this works excellently, except for one strange interaction I haven’t been able to figure out: After any footnote, the effects of \scriptfont0=… is lost — all the math fonts seem to revert to what the packages otherwise provide.  (This is exhibited by adding to your demonstration code: Now a footnote\footnote{footnote}. Now again $\alpha_{1987} = 1987$.)  Do you have any suggestions, or would you prefer I ask this as a separate follow-up question?  A hacky workaround is of course to redefine the footnote command to reissue \scriptfont0=\sfnt after it’s added the actual footnote.

ah I should have mentioned that:-) You need to re-assert that after any size change (as latex resets the math fonts at size changes)  @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I added a note to the answer

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine if you really wanted a transparent version with no in-document resetting then you would need to set this for every size not just normalsize in which case you'd need to get rid of the hard coded 7.3 etc and it would get more complicated than I was planning just now...

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine just had a thought a better way that would fit with latex would be not to mess with tex primitives but simply use an adjusted fd file for the old style font that uses the other font at sizes below 10pt if you didn't want this to affect \small etc you would need a new font family. Too late now but I may add something tomorrow

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine answer updated

I was just sitting over my morning coffee getting ready to try messing with the *.fd file myself following your suggestion, and then I got the notification of this answer update. You (and the other power users here) really are wizards!

Just in case no pdfLaTeX-based solution is forthcoming, here's a solution that works with the unicode-math package under LuaLaTeX. (Actually, the solution works under XeLaTeX as well, except that you'll have to replace the abstract font names -- "Libertinus Serif" and "Libertinus Math" -- with the exact file names -- "LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf" and "LibertinusMath-Regular.otf".) The solution employs the range, script-font and sscript-font features of the unicode-math package.

% !TEX TS-program = lualatex    
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}[Numbers=OldStyle]
% 'Libertinus Math' doesn't appear to have oldstyle numerals
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math} 
\setmathfont{Libertinus Serif}[%
               range=up/{num}, Numbers=OldStyle,
               script-font ={Libertinus Math},
               sscript-font={Libertinus Math}]
   
\begin{document}
Consider 1987, when $\alpha_{1987} = 1987$.

0123456789

$0123456789\scriptstyle 0123456789\scriptscriptstyle 0123456789$
\end{document}

